# Elapsed time in Matlab in milliseconds with different dates

Tags: matlab, datetime, negative-number, elapsedtime

I want to compute the elapsed time (in milliseconds) of data like this:

> START: 2013-05-04 23:13:06.188
>   ENDED: 2013-05-05 1:22:41.617

I can't use `etime()` because I need the elapsed time in milliseconds. When I use a for loop for something like this:

```
[start_i, end_i] = regexp(data{i}, '\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+.\d+');
temp_str = data{i};
time{i} = cellstr(temp_str(start_i:end_i));

n1 = datenum(datevec(time{i-1}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'));
n2 = datenum(datevec(time{i}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'));

n = n2 - n1
```

It gives the following error:

> Error using dtstr2dtvecmx
>   Failed on converting date string to date number.
>
> Error in datevec (line 118)
>               y = dtstr2dtvecmx(t,icu_dtformat);
>
> Error in test (line 40)
>           n1 = datenum(datevec(time{i-1}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'));

if I use `datevec()` like this:

```
[start_i, end_i] = regexp(data{i}, '\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+');
temp_str = data{i};
time{i} = cellstr(temp_str(start_i:end_i));

t1 = datevec(time{i-1}, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
t2 = datevec(time{i}, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');

t = t2 - t1
datevec(t)
```

it's decreasing the time segments, element by element (seconds with seconds, minutes with minutes, etc) and give negative numbers sometimes.

I think there should be a neat way of doing this without any need of fixing the negative values manually. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
%# your data
data = {
    'START: 2013-05-04 23:13:06.188'
    'ENDED: 2013-05-05 1:22:41.617'
};

%# extract date/time strings
s = regexprep(data, '^\w+: ', '');

%# convert to serial date number (in units of days)
t1 = datenum(s{1}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');
t2 = datenum(s{2}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');

%# difference in seconds
diff_sec = (t2-t1) * 24 * 3600
```

Comment: in fact `datenum` does accept a cell array of strings, so you you write a vectorized call: `t = datenum(s, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')`